# Python Regular expression simple

Tags: python, regex

I want to find all occurrences of LocalizedString(...) in a text file. Between parenthesis, anything could be included. How can I find this using regular expressions?
I searched online but had no luck.
Thank you

Lets say we have a file with the following string:

```
class MyClass { 
   func myFunc(){
        var text = LocalizedString("arrow.Find")
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some input and output?

Comment: this is pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

```
r"LocalizedString\([^)]*\)"
```

1. `LocalizedString\(` matches `LocalizedString(` literally.
2. `[^)]*` matches anything that isn't a closing parenthesis.
3. `\)` matches a closing parenthesis literally.

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"LocalizedString\([^)]*\)")
>>> regex.match('LocalizedString(a,b)')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 20), match='LocalizedString(a,b)'>
```

Note that the match for code like `LocalizedString(a(x),b)` is *not* the entire string:

```
>>> regex.match('LocalizedString(a(x),b)')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 20), match='LocalizedString(a(x)'>
```

This happens because regular expressions can't handle arbitrarily nested parentheses such as `a(b(c(x())))`.

---

You could also eagerly match *everything* that's between any two parentheses, going as far as possible till there are no more closing parentheses:

```
>>> regex2 = re.compile(r"LocalizedString\(.*\)")
>>> regex2.match('LocalizedString(a(x),b)')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 23), match='LocalizedString(a(x),b)'>
>>> regex2.match('LocalizedString(a(x),b) && print("Hello!")')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 42), match='LocalizedString(a(x),b) && print("Hello!")'>
```

---

To match just what's inside the parentheses:

```
r"LocalizedString\(([^)]*)\)"
```

Then the capture group `([^)]*)` will contain the required data:

```
>>> regex3 = re.compile(r"LocalizedString\(([^)]*)\)")
>>> regex3.match('LocalizedString(a,b)').groups()
('a,b',)
>>> regex3.match('LocalizedString(a(x),b)').groups()
('a(x',)
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the matched text (the ... part only)?

Comment: @GeorgeTermentzoglou Try this `re.findall(r'\(.[^\)]+.',string)`.

Comment: @GeorgeTermentzoglou, also see edit to my answer